# OOP(object oriented programming on C++) is necessary to be studied before study c#?

Tags: c#, c++, oop

Is is necessary to study Object Oriented Programming before study C# ? Some of my collage fiends and relatives said this to me that you have to familiar with OOP(object oriented programming on c++) before getting started with the C# ? Is the said thing is really true or i can go on with C# before knowing Object Oriented Programming. Please answer my question.

Comment: C# is an object oriented language so having a familiarity with the principles of object oriented design and programming would be a big plus for sure. On the other hand, you can certainly start learning the syntax of the C# language without much knowledge of OOP. All-in-all I'd say that C# is a great language to learn OOP with.

Comment: You are asking if you need to learn OOP before learning an OOP language. No. Otherwise you would have to learn something before C++!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not **have** to study OOP before learning C#. You can write C# code imperatively if you want (not that I would ever do so). Also, OOP is not specific to C++, it is a set of design concepts and programming structures that apply to many modern languages.

That being said, you **should** learn OOP soon. Languages like C# are build around OOD (Object-Oriented Design), so understanding the concepts will greatly improve your code.

You can certainly learn them at the same time, or study OOP after getting the basics of C# down.

Comment: I will study C++ in my university next year, yet i have only the concepts of C-language, so what you suggest me, should i have an extra course of C# during my holidays before starting up with my next year or not?.

Comment: @HassaanBaig The advantage to learning C++ *before* C# is that you get a feel for a lot of the concepts that C# gives you for free, which in my opinion, tends to make you a better programmer. That being said, since you are going to learn both, I would say go ahead and take the C# course. Just be prepared for a pretty large paradigm switch from C.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not necessary.

There is no fundamental reason why you need to learn one particular programming language before learning a different programming language.  There is a lot of stuff in C++ that does not translate to C# and ultimately may wind up confusing you if your ultimate goal is to learn C#.

Learning OOP concepts will happen naturally as you learn C#.

If you want to learn both languages then by all means, study them both, but one is not a prerequisite for the other.

Comment: May be where are reasones to know Java, Delphi ( C# inspired by them). Additionally C# has some relations with VB, Python and Javascript. But it can be even said that C# is AGAINST C++ and INSTEAD OF C++ but not descendant or relative of C++

Comment: C# is most closely related to Java in syntax and concepts.  C# inherits a lot of C/C++-style syntax through Java, but shares only the most basic OOP concepts with C++.